# How can I change the response when an error occurs?

Tags: json, xml, symfony, syntax-error, runtime-error

Sometimes when an error occurs such as an uncaught exception or a syntax error then an html page gets rendered displaying info related to the error. It there a way to return response in a way the request is provided.

In other words if I provide an http request that has `content-type: application/json` on its header then the errorous response should also have `content-type: application/json` with the appropriate response otherwise if a `content-type:application/xml` is given then response gets provided then it should return the same header and apropriate content.

Do you have any idea how I will do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very detailed documentation show you how to custom your exception pages. It show you how to create your own exception controller and exception listener as well. [How to Customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)